# Apache 2 wraps whole HTML that should be rendered in <pre> tag

Tags: php, html, apache, pre

In my project I have a php file with following structure:

```
<?php //here some php to receive data from external API ?>

<html><head>Some head data</head><body>

HTML content

</body></html>
```

On my localost (Ubuntu 14, Apache 2, PHP 5.5.9) everything works fine, but on remote server (Debian 6, Apache 2, PHP 5.3.3) instead of rendered page I get printed HTML code. The reason is that my HTML is wrapped like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>

<pre>
Here my whole HTML
</pre>

</body></html>
```

That is the first problem I met, for which I could't Google anything, so I will appreciate any and every help ;)

It may be relevant that I deal with uploaded file in PHP part.

Comment: Had the same problem. Found a solution? If yes, could you share it?